# Please Help When Removing Multiple SelectedIndices Integers

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Everything Is Proceeding Successfully, Both The Plain Text & MD5 Hashes Are Adding To ListBoxes Perfectly, But When Removing The Same Indices Which I'm Removing In The Password List, I Want To Remove In The MD5 List Too. It's Functionally Completely When I Remove One Seleceted Item, But When I Remove More Than One Seleceted Item In The Password List I Get An Error When Removing From The MD5List.

I'm Basically Getting The Selected Indices In The Password List, & Using A Loop To Remove The Same Indices Integers Selected In Password List, To Remove In MD5 List.

Comment: I second the motion from Caius Jard. Your post is very hard to read because of your using title case. If you make it hard for us to help you, you're less likely to get the help you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with using distinct items in each list then I would suggest that you do this:

```vb
Dim indexes = PasswordList.SelectedIndices.Cast(Of Integer)().Reverse().ToArray()

For Each index In indexes
    PasswordList.Items.RemoveAt(index)
    MD5ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index)
Next
```

The first line creates an array containing the indexes of the items you want to remove from each list. That array is completely independent of both `ListBoxes` so it will be unaffected by any change you make to either list.

The array is also in decreasing order. What that means is that, if you remove items at those indexes in order, the remaining items will be unaffected by that change. When you remove an item, the index of all subsequent items is decremented by 1. That means removing items by ascending index is problematic. Removing them by descending index avoids any issues.

Having said all that, you really shouldn't be removing items like this because you shouldn't be adding them like you are in the first place. What you should be doing is creating a single object for each password and MD5 pair, adding those objects to a single list and then binding that list to both `ListBoxes`. You then simply remove a single item from that single list and both `ListBoxes` will be affected.

```vb
Public Class PasswordData

    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property MD5Hash As String

End Class
```

```vb
Private ReadOnly passwordDatas As New BindingList(Of PasswordData)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    passwordDataBindingSource.DataSource = passwordDatas

    passwordListBox.DisplayMember = "Password"
    passwordListBox.DataSource = passwordDataBindingSource

    md5HashListBox.DisplayMember = "MD5Hash"
    md5HashListBox.DataSource = passwordDataBindingSource
End Sub

Private Sub AddPassword()
    passwordDatas.Add(New PasswordData With {.Password = passwordTextBox.Text,
                                             .MD5Hash = md5hashTextBox.Text})
End Sub
```

You can then get the items selected in one `ListBox` and it covers the data in both, so you just remove those items from one list and both `ListBoxes` will be affected:

```vb
Dim selectedItems = passwordListBox.SelectedItems.Cast(Of PasswordData)().ToArray()

For Each selectedItem In selectedItems
    passwordDatas.Remove(selectedItem)
Next
```

Because there's only one list, you can deal with the items directly, rather than their indexes, so there's no need to reverse the order of the array.